# Javascript Validate textbox is null if null color background

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

```
SELECT 
apex_item.text(1, NULL, 4, 4, NULL, 'f01_#ROWNUM#') ONE,
apex_item.text(2, NULL, 4, 4,   'onclick="port(#ROWNUM#);"', 'f02_#ROWNUM#') TWO 
FROM DUAL
```

I need to validate two text box in the above query on a button click and onclick event, When they are null highlight with background color. and prompt a alert message.

I am using the below javascript function. But this is not working. Please suggest me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function port(pRow) {
   if ( $x_Item('f01_'+pRow).val = ' ) then   {
       alter('Empty');  
   } 
}
</script>
```

Thanks
Sudhir

Comment: Is the query your actual query or is it an example and can the real query contain multiple rows? It is a tabular form? Can new rows be added?

Comment: You are mixing JavaScript en PL/SQL :D Simply use `if ($x_Item('f01_'+pRow).value = '')` instead of `if ( $x_Item('f01_'+pRow).val = ' ) then` and it should do the job. I suggest you to look at the Javascript console (or even better, to use plugins like Firebug), it should have warned you about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript syntax seems wrong.
Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
   var list = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
   for (var x = 0; x < list.length; x++){
      var txb = list[x];
      if (txb.getAttribute('type').toLowerCase() == 'text'){
        if ( txb.value == '' ) {
           txb.style.backgroundColor = '#a00';
        } 
        else{
            txb.style.backgroundColor = ''; //return to default color
        }
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

I don't know your page structure, so this script isn't the most efficient way but it should work.
You simply have to call the JS function "validate()" whenever you want to check your textbox values.

Comment: This function is not working. Requirement is like this there are two textbox on the screen if any one is not entered it must alter a message and change the color background of the textbox. Please suggest me some javascript.